# Como usar hiperlink para planilhar com celula selecionada?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu objetivo é ao clicar na celular o usuário seja direcionado para a planilha estando a linha selecionada, como está na imagem acima ele está selecionando a linha de forma manual.

A linha de código que precisa alterar essa abaixo, preciso de ajuda.

```
=HIPERLINK("#BRG83204D4!A2";"BRG83204D4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da área do desenvolvedor do excel, execute o código VBA trocando os valores pela suas variáveis, isso pode ajudar resolver seu problema:

```
Sub test()
 With Worksheets("Sua planilha")
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("Sua celula"), _
     Address:="Caminho a ser direcionado", _
     ScreenTip:="Mensagem que ira aparecer ao passar o mouse", _
     TextToDisplay:="Mensagem que ira aparecer na celula"
 End With
End Sub
```